# Comparar dos JSON y obtener otro JSON con las diferencias

Tags: jquery, json, lodash

Buenas tengo una duda de si puedo construir un tercer JSON a partir de las diferencias de otros dos tengo los siguientes dos json:

```
[{"id":"4537","descripcion":"3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE NE","cantidad":"1","precio":"300","total":"300"},{"id":"4538","descripcion":"3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE RJ","cantidad":"1","precio":"300","total":"300"}]

[{"id":"4537","descripcion":"3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE NE","cantidad":"1","precio":"300","total":"300"},{"id":"4539","descripcion":"3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE RS","cantidad":"1","precio":"300","total":"300"}]
```

Quiero compararlos ya estuve investigando y quería usar una Liberia llamada [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) pero solo me regresa dos valores algo así `{107: '8', 145: 'J'}`

asi es como estoy comparadndo lo valores

```
        var remoteJSON = $("#listaProductos2").val();
        var localJSON = $("#listaProductos3").val();

        console.log( _.isEqual(remoteJSON, localJSON) );
        const result = _.pickBy(remoteJSON, (v, k) => !_.isEqual(localJSON[k], v))

        console.log(result)
```

me gustaría tener un resultado como mis primeros dos JSON algo tal que así : `[{"id":"4538","descripcion":"3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE RJ","cantidad":"1","precio":"300","total":"300"}]` de igual manera si saben otra forma de solucionarlo estaría bien no tiene que ser con la Liberia ya que apenas la descubrí y solo la estaría usando para esto .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en tu caso se trata de dos arreglos podemos usar un método de arreglos llamado [differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/#differenceWith) que recibe los dos objetos a comparar y un ultimo parámetro que es una función para compararlos comúnmente llamada comparador. Usaremos la función que ya habías hallado como comparador.

```js
var remoteJSON = [{
  "id": "4537",
  "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE NE",
  "cantidad": "1",
  "precio": "300",
  "total": "300"
}, {
  "id": "4538",
  "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE RJ",
  "cantidad": "1",
  "precio": "300",
  "total": "300"
}]
var localJSON = [{
  "id": "4537",
  "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE NE",
  "cantidad": "1",
  "precio": "300",
  "total": "300"
}, {
  "id": "4539",
  "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW P30 LITE RS",
  "cantidad": "1",
  "precio": "300",
  "total": "300"
}]

var difference = _.differenceWith(remoteJSON, localJSON, _.isEqual);

console.log(difference)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```